# How to solve CTRL-t key binding issue for fzf?

Tags: command-line, terminal, homebrew, fzf

I recently found this command line tool called [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf). I installed it according to the instructions and it does work, except for the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> key binding. Even though, I installed the special stuff with the key bindings as per their instructions, and I also tried installing fzf downloaded from the git repo as opposed to via homebrew, all the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> key binding does, still, is swap the last two characters.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/817351/how-to-use-fzf-on-mac-terminal-with-bash#817469) discussion about this, but none of the answers offered worked for me.

edit: you can see it in the first video [here](http://brendandawes.com/blog/fzf) what I want to achieve.
edit 2: I'm using the Terminal of MacOs.

Comment: In my case, `ctrl+t` split current window and `fzf` runs in a `tmux` pannel, is this what you want?

Comment: @nbari what I want to achieve is what is shown in the first embedded video here: http://brendandawes.com/blog/fzf

Comment: I guess something overwrote your ctrl-t mapping. type `:call fzf#vim#maps('n')` and search for `'<C-T>`. what do you see?

Comment: @sudavid4 doesn't work, that line entered into the mac terminal gives me this error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: not in the terminal in vim!

Comment: @sudavid4 ok, right, sorry. typed it into vim, got this `E117: Unknown function: fzf#vim#maps`

Comment: that's odd... what about `:FZF` is this defined? do you have [fzf-vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) installed?(if you run `:scriptnames` do you have some `fzf.vim` entry?

Comment: @sudavid4 no, I dont' have fzf-vim installed, I am simply trying to use fzf to find and open files quickly from the command line, as in typing `open ` then pressing CTRL-t and, when, ideally, fzf appears, I press Enter on the file I need, which then opens.

Comment: I suggest you install fzf.vim, it'll solve your issue. If you'd rather "do it yourself" then I wish you good luck.

Answer (score 11):

I use `zsh` with `Oh My Zsh` on Mac.

If I put `fzf` before `vi-mode` in the plugin setting in `.zshrc` like

```
plugins=(... fzf ... vi-mode ...)
```

`Ctrl-t` does not work showing `^T`. `Ctrl-r` does not work, either.

But, if `fzf` comes AFTER `vi-mode` like

```
plugins=(... vi-mode ... fzf ...)
```

no problem arises.

Answer (score 6):

If you clone fzf from the repository it contains a file called `fzf/shell/key-bindings.zsh` which refers to

```
fzf-file-widget() {
  LBUFFER="${LBUFFER}${__fsel}"
  local ret=$?
  zle redisplay
  typeset -f zle-line-init >/dev/null && zle-line-init
  return $ret
}
zle -N fzf-file-widget
bindkey "^T" fzf-file-widget
```

the Control-T keybinding. This is normally sourced by your `.zshrc`

```
[ -f ~/.fzf.zsh ] && source ~/.fzf.zsh
```

which should contain its reference in `.fzf.zsh`:

```
source "$HOME/.fzf/shell/key-bindings.zsh"
```

If your keybinding does not work then your keybinding may be overwritten by your zshrc or may not be invoked by your zshrc.

Comment: hi, I did pretty much what you outlined here, but still failed to get the key-bindings to work. i am using zsh; installed using homebrew and ran that `/usr/local/opt/fzf/install` which prompted me to install key-bindings and added those lines to my .zshrc. the **TAB works however. can you please provide some troubleshooting assistance?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [zsh-vi-mode](https://github.com/jeffreytse/zsh-vi-mode), then replace this line

```
[ -f ~/.fzf.zsh ] && source ~/.fzf.zsh
```

with this

```
zvm_after_init_commands+=('[ -f ~/.fzf.zsh ] && source ~/.fzf.zsh')
```

From zsh-vi-mode GitHub [page](https://github.com/jeffreytse/zsh-vi-mode#execute-extra-commands)

---

Psst! if you use [fzf-tab](https://github.com/Aloxaf/fzf-tab), you might want to enable that also

```
zvm_after_init_commands+=('[ -f ~/.fzf.zsh ] && source ~/.fzf.zsh && enable-fzf-tab')
```

Answer (score 2):

I put the below script in my .zshrc and sourced it using `source ~/.zshrc`

```sh
if [ -x "$(command -v fzf)"  ]
then
    source /usr/share/fzf/key-bindings.zsh
fi
```

and now key bindings (CTRL-T, CTRL-R, and ALT-C) work for me.

got the above script from [how to enable hotkeys for fzf](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/how-to-enable-the-hotkeys-for-fzf/11723/3)

##### explanation

you have `key-bindings.zsh` inside /usr/share/fzf or a few directories deeper.
Above script only sources `key-bindings.zsh` if fzf is installed.

rest of the working is part of the `key-bindings.zsh`, which frankly I did not bother to
understand.

**OS**: Manjaro GNU-Linux

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> does not work (in bash) when I have the "vi mode" enabled by `set -o vi`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the CTRL-t key combo work as desired. There was one step I had missed.

After installing useful keybindings and fuzzy completion with `/usr/local/opt/fzf/install`, I updated `fzf.bash` manually with `[ -f ~/.fzf.bash ] && source ~/.fzf.bash`. After restarting the Terminal, it now works.

Edit: Also, this line needs to be added to your .bash_profile or .bashrc: `source ~/.fzf.bash`.